# Receive user name and password from user using jbutton

Tags: java, jbutton, jpasswordfield

I'm having trouble with using jbuttonactionperformed to receive a username and password in java. What is wrong with this code. I searched in google and saw that a character array is used to store getPassword return.Is it wrong?

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    char[] input = {'r','o','o','t'};
    if (jTextField1.getText() == "admin" && jPasswordField1.getPassword() == input) {
        srchnm.main(null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never compare Strings and avoid comparing other reference types using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` method for Strings instead, and for the password, the java.util.Arrays class has an equals method you can use.

```
if (java.util.Arrays.equals(jPasswordField1.getPassword(), input) && 
           "admin".equals(jTextField1.getText())) {
    srchnm.main(null);
}
```

Alternately, you could change this:

```
"admin".equals(jTextField1.getText())
```

to

```
"admin".equalsIgnoreCase(jTextField1.getText())
```

Myself (Hovercraft), I like to use String constants so as to avoid debugging typing errors:

```
// at the top
public static final String ADMIN = "admin";

// ....

// a boolean statement in the if block:
ADMIN.equals(jTextField1.getText())
```

Comment: Made into a community wiki as I should not get credit for this answer for a question that has been asked over and over.

Comment: can i use equals for character array too?

Comment: @JithinSebastian: see edit to answer.